# Python 3.7.3 import pandas throws error: ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

On `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, I do have `Python 2.7.15rc1`, `Python 3.6.7` and `Python 3.7.3`. When I try to `import padas`, it works fine with `Python 2.7.15rc1` and  `Python 3.6.7` but with `Python 3.7.3` it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I also upgrade numpy and pandas using the following commands

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade numpy
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

But getting the same error. Any hints, please.

**Edited**

1. I guess the problem is with `numpy`, when I tried import `numpy` it throws the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
>     from . import multiarray
> ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
>     from . import add_newdocs
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
>     from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
>     from .type_check import *
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
>     import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
>     raise ImportError(msg)
> ImportError: 
> Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
> likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
> If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
> files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)
> ```

2. Is it safe to uninstall `Python 3.6.7`?

Comment: What is your `pandas` version?

Comment: To which python version does pip3 refer? Might it be possible that the versions of python (3.7) and pip3 are not aligned?

Comment: Thanks @w4bo for your comment. I do have the same feeling and do not know how to fix it. I'm new to python. Any hints. please.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh answer is going in this direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your `pandas` version? I have Python 3.7.3 on my Mac and `0.24.2` version of pandas, and `import pandas` works as below.

```
$ python3.7 -V
Python 3.7.3
$ python3.7
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.24.2'
```

Also try `pip3.7` in your installation instead of `pip3`

Comment: What does `which pip3.7` and `which pip3` gives you?

Comment: pip3.7: command not found and also I can not check pandas version since can't import pandas

Comment: I guess since you have two `python 3.x`, it might be causing issues! Uninstall one of them and check!

Answer (score 0):

I think you sould include numpy as well in your project
If not, try the following commands :

```
pip3 uninstall pandas
pip3 uninstall numpy
pip3 install pandas
pip3 install numpy
```